# Fixing inconsistent formatting of 24-hour to 12-hour

Tags: python, pandas, time, formatting, data-cleaning

**I need to essentially measure how much each employee gets paid during each hour of work. There was some data cleaning to do and so I'm trying to make the formatting consistent.
It is a homework problem and its proving tough. I am new to python so please feel free to compress the code. I'm trying to use the pandas database.**

csv file in pandas

```
   break_notes end_time  pay_rate start_time
0        15-18    23:00      10.0      10:00
1  18.30-19.00    23:00      12.0      18:00
2      4PM-5PM    22:30      14.0      12:00
3          3-4    18:00      10.0      09:00
4     4-4.10PM    23:00      20.0      09:00
5      15 - 17    23:00      10.0      11:00
6      11 - 13    16:00      10.0      10:00
'''

import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np


work_shifts = pd.read_csv('work_shifts.csv')
break_shifts = work_shifts['break_notes'].str.extract('(?P<start>[\d\.]+)?\D*(?P<end>[\d\.]+)?')

print(work_shifts)

for i in range(len(break_shifts['start'])):
    if '.' not in break_shifts['start'][i]: 
        break_shifts['start'][i] = break_shifts['start'][i] + ':00'
    else:
        break_shifts['start'][i] = break_shifts['start'][i].replace('.',':')

for i in range(len(break_shifts['end'])):
    if '.' in str(break_shifts['end'][i]): 
        break_shifts['end'][i] = break_shifts['end'][i].replace('.',':')
    elif '.' not in str(break_shifts['end'][i]):
        break_shifts['end'][i] = break_shifts['end'][i] + ':00'

for i in range(len(break_shifts['end'])):
    break_shifts['end'][i] = datetime.datetime.strptime(break_shifts['end'][i], '%H:%M').time()
    break_shifts['start'][i] = datetime.datetime.strptime(break_shifts['start'][i], '%H:%M').time()

work_shifts[['start_break','end_break']] = break_shifts[['start', 'end']]

for i in range(len(work_shifts['end_time'])):
    work_shifts['end_time'][i] = datetime.datetime.strptime(work_shifts['end_time'][i], '%H:%M').time()

for i in range(len(work_shifts['start_time'])):
    work_shifts['start_time'][i] = datetime.datetime.strptime(work_shifts['start_time'][i], '%H:%M').time()

print(work_shifts)
```

**this is the result**

```
   break_notes  end_time  pay_rate start_time start_break end_break
0        15-18  23:00:00      10.0   10:00:00    15:00:00  18:00:00
1  18.30-19.00  23:00:00      12.0   18:00:00    18:30:00  19:00:00
2      4PM-5PM  22:30:00      14.0   12:00:00    04:00:00  05:00:00
3          3-4  18:00:00      10.0   09:00:00    03:00:00  04:00:00
4     4-4.10PM  23:00:00      20.0   09:00:00    04:00:00  04:10:00
5      15 - 17  23:00:00      10.0   11:00:00    15:00:00  17:00:00
6      11 - 13  16:00:00      10.0   10:00:00    11:00:00  13:00:00
```

I tried adding the times but they are inconsistent types. If theres a different approach then please provide guidance. I need to calculate how many employees are working at what time and then calculate how much pay is given to the employees per hour.

My approach was to convert the formatting of the break notes into time then convert the 12-hour to 12 provided both end_break and start_break was before datetime.datetime(12,0,0).

I'm not sure how to calculate the money per hour. Maybe using if statements?